# Как работать с данными JSON в C#

Tags: c#, json

У меня есть json-файл с вопросами и ответами по математике.

Cодержание файла:

```
{
  "module": {
    "number": 1,
    "name": "Mathematics",
    "questions": 30,
    "revision": "2017-08-13"
  },
  "questions": [
    {
      "number": 1,
      "question": "Eighteen thousandths, written as a decimal, is:",
      "answers": [
        "0.0018",
        "0.018",
        "0.18"
      ],
      "correct_answer": 1
    },
    {
      "number": 2,
      "question": "The next number in the sequence <b>1, 3, 6, 10, </b> is:",
      "answers": [
        "12",
        "13",
        "14",
        "15"
      ],
      "correct_answer": 4
    },
    {
      "number": 3,
      "question": "PI is:",
      "answers": [
        "135.3",
        "3.15",
        "3.14",
        "3.16"
      ],
      "correct_answer": 3
    },
    {
      "number": 4,
      "question": "2-2*4 is:",
      "answers": [
        "4",
        "0",
        "8",
        "6"
      ],
      "correct_answer": 4
    },
    {
      "number": 5,
      "question": "10**2 is:",
      "answers": [
        "100",
        "20",
        "300",
        "1000"
      ],
      "correct_answer": 1
    }
  ]
}
```

Вопрос, как работать с данными которые там есть?
Мне нужно задавать юзеру вопросы и кемперить правильный ли ответ он дал.

Comment: Собственно, нужно сначала распарсить (сконвертировать) json в c# класс, затем на клиент (если он есть) отправить `number`, `question`, `answers`, а на сервере получить от клиента `answer` и сопоставить с `correct_answer`

Answer (score 2):

Воспользуйтесь библиотекой System.Text.Json: [How to serialize and deserialize (marshal and unmarshal) JSON in .NET](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json-how-to).

```
install-package System.Text.Json
```

```cs
public class QuestionData {
    public int Number { get; set; }
    public string Question { get; set; }
    public string[] Answers { get; set; }
    [JsonPropertyName("correct_answer")]
    public int CorrectAnswer { get; set; }
}

public class Module {
    public int Number { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Questions { get; set; }
    public DateTime Revision { get; set; }
}
    
public class ModuleData {
    public Module Module { get; set; }
    public QuestionData[] Questions { get; set; }
}
```

```cs
string json = File.ReadAllText("data.json");
JsonSerializerOptions options = new JsonSerializerOptions();
options.PropertyNameCaseInsensitive = true;
var moduleData = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<ModuleData>(json, options);
```